# Improving performance in a query with median

Tags: sql-server, spatial, sql-server-2019

I have the following query that I would like to speed up, I ran it through the Tuner but it didn't suggest any new indexes, so I am looking for some help to improve it. (using SQL Server 2019)

[**Actual Execution Plan**](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJzjpF5Tv)

#### Query

```
declare @p3 sys.geography
set @p3=convert(sys.geography,0xE6100000010C030000408ED64540020000800DDC53C0)
exec sp_executesql N'WITH #myselect
                         AS (SELECT 
                                 BedroomsAvailable
                                 ,ListingId 
                                 ,UnitTypeId
                                 ,Price,
                                 PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Price)  
                                 OVER (PARTITION BY UnitTypeId, BedroomsAvailable) AS MedianCont
                            FROM Listings
                            WHERE ExpiryDate >= GetDate() AND  Price >= @MinFilterPrice AND Price <= @MaxFilterPrice AND Location.STDistance(@CurrentLocation) <= @RadiusInKms )
                        SELECT BedroomsAvailable 
                            ,COUNT(listingid) AS Count 
                            ,MIN(price) AS MinPrice 
                            ,MAX(price) AS MaxPrice 
                            ,AVG(price) AS AveragePrice
                            ,STDEV(price) as StandardDeviation 
                            ,MIN(MedianCont) MedianPrice
                            ,UnitTypeId
                        FROM #myselect
                        GROUP BY BedroomsAvailable, UnitTypeId
                        ORDER BY UnitTypeId',N'@CurrentLocation [geography],@RadiusInKms int,@MinFilterPrice decimal(3,0),@MaxFilterPrice decimal(5,0)',@CurrentLocation=@p3,@RadiusInKms=20000,@MinFilterPrice=100,@MaxFilterPrice=10000
```

#### Indexes

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [16_HHHH] ON [dbo].[Listings]
(
    [Location]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = HIGH,LEVEL_2 = HIGH,LEVEL_3 = HIGH,LEVEL_4 = HIGH), 
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [16_MMMM] ON [dbo].[Listings]
(
    [Location]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_2 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_3 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_4 = MEDIUM), 
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [256_HHHH] ON [dbo].[Listings]
(
    [Location]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = HIGH,LEVEL_2 = HIGH,LEVEL_3 = HIGH,LEVEL_4 = HIGH), 
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 256, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Listings_CityId] ON [dbo].[Listings]
(
    [CityId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Listings] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Listings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ListingID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

---

Didn't really make a difference removing the order by clause.

```
SELECT (your columns) 
INTO #temptable 
FROM Listings 
WHERE Location.STDistance(@CurrentLocation) <= @RadiusInKms
```

Using a temp table then running the rest on the temp table seem to have made it slower in general, ran it multiple times 200ms original vs 300ms with temp table.

My table is pretty big (half a million records) so not sure how I can provide a reproduceable example of the data, I was hoping by just looking at my query and the plan it would be obvious to provide some hints at making it faster.  I will see how I can provide a repo.

This is running on 6 virtual core/32GB HyperV (yes HyperV is bad but it's VPS).

Comment: To help set expectations for people trying to answer: this query runs for 370ms. How fast do you need it to be?

Comment: Does plan change when moving GetDate() execution out to param assignment and adding covering non-clustered index with leading key as the more selective of ExpiryDate vs. Price?  If so, please post.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5)` to find the median, use one of the better performing options listed in the references from Aaron Bertrand below:

- [What is the fastest way to calculate the median](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/median)

  Example:

  ```
  DECLARE @c BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.EvenRows);

  SELECT AVG(1.0 * val)
  FROM (
       SELECT val FROM dbo.EvenRows
        ORDER BY val
        OFFSET (@c - 1) / 2 ROWS
        FETCH NEXT 1 + (1 - @c % 2) ROWS ONLY
  ) AS x;
  ```
- [Best approaches for grouped median](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/02/t-sql-queries/grouped-median)

  Example:

  ```
  SELECT   d.SalesPerson, w.Median
  FROM
  (
     SELECT SalesPerson, COUNT(*) AS y
     FROM dbo.Sales
     GROUP BY SalesPerson
  ) AS d
  CROSS APPLY
  (
     SELECT AVG(0E + Amount)
     FROM
     (
        SELECT z.Amount
        FROM dbo.Sales AS z
        WHERE z.SalesPerson = d.SalesPerson
        ORDER BY z.Amount
        OFFSET (d.y - 1) / 2 ROWS
        FETCH NEXT 2 - d.y % 2 ROWS ONLY
     ) AS f
  ) AS w(Median);
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Try to move from `percentile_cont` to  `APPROX_PERCENTILE_CONT`

In this [example](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/announcing-general-availability-of-approximate-percentile/bc-p/3773395/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8dG9waWNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9ufExGSUlVOThXWDE4QzYxfDM3NzMzOTV8U1VCU0NSSVBUSU9OU3xoSw#M1377) it pushed the speed from ~13 seconds to ~1.5 seconds.

Full documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/approx-percentile-cont-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Keep in mind that Microsoft says:

> "The function implementation guarantees up to a 1.33% error."